# Do Game-Maker scripts save the variables or are they deleted after excecution?

Tags: scripting, game-maker

When i make a script that excecutes at the beggining and has a var ammo and that finishes excecution, will i be able to call the var ammo in other scripts or it will be deleted? If it will not be deleted, will I be able to change its value on other scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who calls the script? Or rather, where did you put the call to the script? Is it in the room initialization code or is it in an object's code? That makes a large difference.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be expanded to almost all modern languages. The short answer is: no, it won't, the long answer is:

In programming, there's a word called `scope`, a scope is a chunk of code defined by the enclosing statements in the programming language (in most of the languages, they're brackets {}). There can be multiple scopes inside another scopes, creating a hierarchy system.

A scope has 2 types of variables. local and global. Global variables are defined in a parent scope, and can be overriden by local variables. Local variables are only available in that scope or the child-scopes. They get removed once the scope is removed. If you name a loca, variable the same as a global, the global gets overridden but it dodsn't get deleted, nor changed.

In your case, ammo is a local variable to script "A". Once script "A" is finished, ammo gets deleted, and can't be reached by other scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. If so, how can i reach ammo from other scripts?

Comment: Dunno, I'm not a game make developer, there's surely some way to make it global.

Comment: I finally found how to. In case someome is reading this you must add a global. Before your name var ex global.ammo = 0;

Comment: @Bálint If you are not a game maker programmer, then please don't assume such things about scope. In Game Maker there is only global scope, object scope, and script argument scope. The last is explicitly defined via the "argument[]" array. So no, ammo will not be deleted. It will either be a global variable or an instances local variable.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck First of all, I never assumed anything. If I post an answer about an engine, language or framework I don't use, then I research it before. As stated on the **main game maker page** and I quote "local: these variables must be declared using the "var" function. A local variable is only valid for the event or script resource in which it is created. So GameMaker: Studio will create the variable, use it for the duration of the event and then "forget" it again, meaning that if you try to use it later you will get an "unknown variable" error."

Comment: @Bálint Well, I will be honest and just give you a fair word of warning. Their documentation screws up on that sort of stuff routinely. That doesn't occur in practice when used in the room editor. The room starting code and individually set object creation code falls outside of the range of "events and script resources". So, depending on where the code is located this question can have wildly different results. (Also, I was not aware the var keyword had changed meaning. In legacy code it merely created a variable without having to instantiate it. Still my point holds.)

Comment: I would recommend maybe adding a little specifying it's behavior is mildly unpredictable. This is exactly the sort of bug I'd expect that thing to have. It's known for such issues. One has to take their documentation quite literally if it is even true half the time.